# Can ASP.NET Core save objects in memory while running?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to save objects in memory while ASP.NET Core is running? How can `EntityList` below be accessed from a transient object like a SignalR Hub?

**Program.cs**

```
namespace ASPNETCoreApp
{
    public class Program
    {

        public List<Entity> EntityList = new List<Entity>();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            Entity Entity1 = new Entity();
            EntityList.Add(Entity1);
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give any more info about the problem you are trying to solve? is it that you want 1..* clients connecting to your app through signalR that will all be reading and writing from the same logical data source ?

Answer (score -1):

You could use an in memory cache - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Or if you are using a transient object create a service which will provide a singleton for each request.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#singleton

Comment: Which one of these would ensure that the object remains in memory until the server is shut down?

Comment: @crayden the in memory cache would be the better choice for you

Comment: html is stateless per se. So even different requests might recreate a singleton. You need to save session state and/or application state to not lose data between requests. You might be able to leverage global memory as suggested above but then you depend on the web server. But as soon as your app gets served by more than one server, you'll have to use some more robust solutions. I'd consider session state or application state with some backing storage in SQL or file or whatever

Comment: The clients will be connecting in real time through SignalR, so reading/writing will be frequent. There will only be one web server involved. What would be the best way to implement session or application state for this scenario?

Comment: if you have concurrent requests trying to read and write from/to a single collection you open yourself up to threading issues, race conditions etc - I would advise using a thread safe collection if possible - also it sounds like you don't necessarily need to persist the data outside of the application context, do you actually need a persistence mechanism